# ListView item background hell

Tags: android, android-listview

Because checkbox isnt an option for my project I want the checkable to have a background when checked.Supporting from 2.3 i havent manage to solve this problem yet.
Selection is correct but what i see at screen isnt.Random color at random row..

[image]

Fist i have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light" />
       <item  android:drawable="@drawable/abs__list_selector_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

-

```
 public class CheckableRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout implements
        Checkable {

    private boolean isChecked;
    private List<Checkable> checkableViews;


    private static final int[] CheckedStateSet = {
        R.attr.state_checked
    };

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise(attrs);
    }

    public CheckableRelativeLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
        super(context);
        initialise(null);
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#isChecked()
     */
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#setChecked(boolean)
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean isChecked) {
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.setChecked(isChecked);
        }
    }

    /*
     * @see android.widget.Checkable#toggle()
     */
    public void toggle() {
        this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
        for (Checkable c : checkableViews) {
            c.toggle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        final int childCount = this.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            findCheckableChildren(this.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CheckedStateSet);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        toggle();
        return super.performClick();
    }


    /**
     * Read the custom XML attributes
     */
    private void initialise(AttributeSet attrs) {
        this.isChecked = false;
        this.checkableViews = new ArrayList<Checkable>(5);
    }

    /**
     * Add to our checkable list all the children of the view that implement the
     * interface Checkable
     */
    private void findCheckableChildren(View v) {
        if (v instanceof Checkable) {
            this.checkableViews.add((Checkable) v);
        }

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            final int childCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
                findCheckableChildren(vg.getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What i get is this

Comment: May I ask why iterate all children when setting background of the  parent layout only will do ?

Comment: i think it is pointless but i found that sample like that :)

Comment: You are using the same drawable (abs__list_selector_holo_light) for all states

Comment: i know but is this the problem ? why there are different colors then ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a clean example on making a `Checkable` View:

```
import android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ActivatedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable{

    public static final int[] CHECKED_STATE = {R.attr.state_checked};
    private boolean mChecked;

    public ActivatedLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ActivatedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ActivatedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }


    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean b) {
        mChecked = b;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        mChecked = !mChecked;
        refreshDrawableState();
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        int[] states =  super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (mChecked){
            mergeDrawableStates(states, CHECKED_STATE);
        }
        return states;
    }


}
```

And selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checked"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchecked"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: can i use relative layout instead (to test)

Comment: i get exception that 01-14 14:27:34.229: E/AndroidRuntime(16147): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class gr.com.simple.android.widget.CheckableRelativeLayout

Comment: check the reason in the stack trace: 06-24 14:27:53.027: E/AndroidRuntime(9771): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: CheckableLinearLayout(Context,AttributeSet)
so just add this constructor.