# Android ListView with multiple Selection

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a layout file.
In that i want two ListView ,and both ListView with multipleselection.
ListView data i am populating from database.
How to design this layout.
can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. The root View of each item you will display in list must implement Checkable. When implementing this interface also update the drawable state of View. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318182/1531054) for how to do that.
2. Set a  drawable as background for this root View. Which different color/drawables for checked state and normal states.
3. Set ListView's choice mode to single choice or multi-choice.
4. In list adapter, provide item views with above created View as parent layout.

Now, `ListView` will take care of setting checked/unchecked state on its item views. Also you can call `getCheckedItemIds()` or `getCheckedItemPositions()` on ListView to get currently selected items.

You can also check a Scrollview example [here](https://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/android-scrollview-example/)

Comment: I want to design that layout file.I mean to say two Listview in one layout and both Listview  data are populating from database.So how i should design this so that it will looks good.